# LDAP authentication module not working in xampp

Tags: authentication-authorization

When i enabled LDAP module for drupal 7 then always shows error 
No LDAP PHP Extension is loaded for PHP, so LDAP will not work properly.
even  after un comment extension=php_ldap.dll from my php.ini, it is not working.i restart apache and php_ldap.dll is also in php extensions.

Comment: Did you restart your apache server?

Comment: not working after restart apache server.

Comment: Check do you have php_ldap.dll file in your php extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes i have sorted out this issue.
In the \xampp\php folder you will find this file:libsasl.dll
Copy it into the \xampp\apache\bin folder.
Now try and start Apache again.It should now start.Now it is working.

Comment: You could have also added `driveletter:\xampp\php` to the environment variable `PATH` on your machine. This way you won't have to copy and paste all files but you simply tell your machine to also look in your XAMPP's PHP folder.

Comment: Uncomment: extension=php_ldap.dll in php.ini. Add to PATH \xampp\php;\xampp\apache\bin

Answer (score 0):

Cross check following points.

1) Enable extension = php_ldap.dll

2) Check do you have php_ldap.dll file in your php extensions folder. If not, download the file and place it in php extension

3) Restart Apache Server.

Comment: after cross check there is pop up saying.The application has failed to start because libsasl.dll was no found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem , one warning php startup:unable to load dynamic library "\xampp\php\ext\php_ldap.dll"- the specified module could not be found.